# NodeJS return http.request

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi now I know that NodeJS is asynchronous (which I am still trying to get my head around to be honest).

The problem that I am currently facing is I have attempting to do a `http.request` to receive some JSON data. This is fine but what I need is to return this data to  a variable. I believe I need to do a callback function? (from what I have read up on the matter)

**The Code that I currently have:**

```
var http = require('http');
pCLatLng = '';

function postCodeCheck() {
    var pCode = { 
        host: 'geo.jamiethompson.co.uk',
        path: "/" + 'SW1A2AA' + ".json" 
    };

    http.request(pCode).on('response', function(response) {
        var data = '';
        response.on("data", function (chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', function () {
            pCJSON = JSON.parse(data);
            pCLatLng = pCJSON;
        });
        }).end();
}

console.log(pCLatLng);
```

This is obviously outputting "undefined"; I have tried returning the response.on('end') when having return "hi" or anything inside it instead NodeJS outputs the information about the site. If anyone can help with this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`console.log(pCLatLng);` needs to be inside (or inside something called by) the `response.on('end'` callback. The value isn't available until that callback is fired.

Try something like:

```
function postCodeCheck(callback) {
    var pCode = { 
        host: 'geo.jamiethompson.co.uk',
        path: "/" + 'SW1A2AA' + ".json" 
    };

    http.request(pCode).on('response', function(response) {
        var data = '';
        response.on("data", function (chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', function () {
            callback(JSON.parse(data));
        });
        }).end();
}

postCodeCheck(function (pCLatLng)
{
    console.log(pCLatLng);
});
```

Comment: this won't actually create a variable though will it? the console.log(pCLatLng) I was using just to test but using your code trying to return the data to a variable such as 'var x = postCodeCheck(function(pCLatLng) { console.log(pCLatLng); })'; and then to console.log(x); it still states undefined?

Comment: Because you're still not grasping async code. The ``postCodeCheck`` function doesn't return anything, so ``x`` will certainly be ``undefined``. The ``postCodeCheck`` function is passed a function (a callback) that will be executed once the value is available. You *can't* get the value outside of the scope of that callback.

Comment: I see I don't think what I am wanting to do is quite possible then. What I was wanting to do was create a NodeJS module which took a Postal Code / Address; and return the LatLng but it needs to first go to a variable in order to fire off another function for what I wanted to do next. (will have to rethink that one then thanks for your help).

Comment: is it possible that the end function gets triggered before the on?  Im having an issue where not full JSON is returned :(

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
var http = require('http');

function postCodeCheck(cb) {
    var pCode = { 
        host: 'geo.jamiethompson.co.uk',
        path: "/" + 'SW1A2AA' + ".json" 
    };

    http.request(pCode).on('response', function(response) {
        var data = '';
        response.on("data", function (chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', function () {
            var pCJSON = JSON.parse(data);
            cb(pCJSON);
        });
        }).end();
}

postCodeCheck(function(pCLatLng) { console.log(pCLatLng); });
```

Look carefully for the differences before using.

Comment: this won't actually create a variable though will it? the console.log(pCLatLng) I was using just to test but using your code trying to return the data to a variable such as 
'var x = postCodeCheck(function(pCLatLng) { console.log(pCLatLng); })';

and then to console.log(x); it still states undefined?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need your `postCodeCheck()` function to take a callback as well, just like `http.request`. In the world of async, calling callbacks with results takes a similar role to `return`ing results.